# android - метод findViewById(int)

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, меня заинтересовал метод `findViewById`. Он ищет `View` по `id`. Но что он возвращает? Я перевёл `View` в тип `String` и заметил что получается непонятный набор букв. Неужели нельзя один раз его узнать и вместо того, чтобы использовать этот тяжёлый метод делать, например, так?

```
Button button = ((Button)(View)"тут_этот_набор_букв");
```

Извините, если глупый вопрос, просто не пойму почему нельзя? Что вообще такое `View`?

Comment: А что мешает делать так: `Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);`?

Comment: Хахах)))) я прекрасно знаю как искать `View`)) Просто всем известно, что `findViewById` тяжёлый метод. Хотя зачем искать `View`, если ты сам разработчик и `View` можно представить как `String`

Comment: Зачем представлять `View` как `String`, если вам нужно работать непосредственно с `View`? Проще один раз получить `View`, как в примере выше, а потом обращаться к нему уже без всяких `findViewById`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Класс `View` (и его подклассы: `Button`, `TextView` и тд.) это объект какого-то виджета на экране (например кнопки). Данный объект представляет все характеристики и внешний вид того, что вы видите на экране (кнопку), а так же позволяет управлять и изменять его состояние и внешний вид.

Каждый объект в Java имеет метод `toString()`, назначение которого представить объект в виде строки (объекта `String`), в классе `View` он  переопределен и возвращает информацию с основными параметрами данного `View`, а так же имя класса и его хэшкод. Когда вы приводите тип `View` к типу `String` вызывается этот метод.
По полученной данным методом информации вы не сможете получить сам объект (по крайней мере легким способом), а не имея объекта `View` вы не можете проводить с ним манипуляции, свойственные этим объектам (например установить фон или текст).

Метод `findViewById()` возвращает объект класса `View` по его идентификатору на разметке (какой то из виджетов, например кнопку).  Теперь, имея данный экземпляр виджета вы можете вызывать реализованные для него методы, такие как изменение размеров, цвета, текста и т.п. Метод работает таким образом, что получает этот объект из предварительно подготовленного через инфлейт (парсинг разметки) и сгенерированного на его основе класса `R` нужный нам виджет из дерева объектов отображаемых на экране.

По имени класса и его хэшкоду, который возвращает метод `toString()` вы не можете получить доступ к этому дереву, а обработка этих данных, чтобы получить по ним объект будет еще тяжелее работы метода `findViewById()`, в то время, как при изменении состояния (например повороте экрана) эти значения могут изменится и будут вовсе бесполезны, что приведет к падению приложения.

Для уменьшения нагрузки от работы этого метода принято для виджетов, к которым обращаются более одного раза во всей активити получать их однажды в методе `onCreate()` и присваивать ссылки на виджеты  полям класса, доступным в любом методе класса. В дальнейшем обращаться к этим виджетам через эти ссылки, а не повторным вызовом `findViewById()`. В адаптере для этой же цели используется паттерн ViewHolder

```
MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

       btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    public void updateButton(String name){

      btn.setText(name);
    }
}
```

**UPD**: Уточнение. В информации, возвращаемом методом `toString()` содержится и его ID (значение вида *R.id.widget_name*) и теоритически мы могли бы спарсить всю полученную строку и выделить из нее эту информацию, однако это значение получено именно в результате работы метода `findViewById()` и присваивается данный ID созданному с помощью этого метода объекту, то есть у программно созданного виджета:

```
Button button = new Button(context);
```

данного параметра не будет (его ID не определен и он отсутствует в классе `R` так как данный виджет не участвовал в инфлейте).

Таким образом ваша идея вообще теряет какой либо практический смысл - чтобы получить данные из объекта методом `toString()` его надо создать, а создается он методом `findViewById()`, когда же он уже создан, ссылка на него сохраняется в поле класса и дополнительные манипуляции по его получению уже не требуются.

**UPD2** кроме всего прочего, строка кода:

```
Button button = ((Button)(View)"тут_этот_набор_букв");
```

полность некорректна. Объект типа `String` никак нельзя привести к типу `View`, так как он не является его наследником (двойное приведение к типу вообще за гранью понимания основ написания Java-программ)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все с этим понятно :) Да, код, который я привёл глуп, я лишь хотел донести до людей сути вопроса

Answer (score 3):

> Но что он возвращает?

Он возвращает объект класса `View` с заданным `id`.

> Неужели нельзя один раз его узнать

Нет, нельзя, так как после изменения конфигурации устройства некоторые виджеты могут выглядеть по-другому, поэтому после изменения конфигурации устройства перерисовывается `layout` (со всеми его дочерними представлениями) и поэтому нужно снова получить (*уже новые, перерисованные*) объекты класса `View` по их `id`.

А сохранение ссылки на *старый* `View` приведет к утечке памяти: этот `View` уже нигде не используется, но, так как ссылка на него сохранена, то сборщик мусора не сможет уничтожить данный объект.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

В `gradle.build` прописываем

```
android {
    …
    dataBinding.enabled = true
}
```

и в `Activity` вместо

```
setContentView(R.layout.hello_world);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setText("Кнопка");
```

вставить этот код

```
HelloWorldBinding binding = 
    DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.hello_world);
binding.button.setText("Кнопка");
```

Полную информацию можете получить [тут!](https://medium.com/google-developers/no-more-findviewbyid-457457644885#.5tc8f18l7)

Comment: Биндинг еще тяжелее, чем вызов метода `findViewById()`, а именно это волнует автора.